# how can i pass data on the handleronclick reactjs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reactjs, web

this part of the code shows that the button read the id of the clicked row how can i put that data inside the input type

```
 handleOnclick(id) {

}

renderItem(d, i) {


    return <tr key={i} >

  <td> {d.Employee_ID} </td>
        <td>{d.Employee_Name}</td>
        <td>{d.Address }</td> 
        <td><center><button className ="btn btn-info" onClick={this.handleOnclick.bind(this, d.Employee_ID)}   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#UpdateEmployee">Edit</button></center></td>
  <td><center><button className ="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></center></td>

 </tr>
}
```

Comment: I don't really get what you meant, where is that "the input type"?

Comment: <input type="text"
                       value={this.state.Employee_Name}
                       onChange={this.handleOnClick}
                        /> </td>

Comment: Thanks, so what you want is: when the button is clicked, the textbox will change its value (to the clicked employee's name), isn't it ^^ ?

Comment: yes however it's not working >.< ''

Comment: Please try my answer below, and feel free to show more code or errors you may get, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  // ...
  this.state = {
    Employee_Name: '',
  }
}


handleOnclick(id, name) {
  this.setState({
    Employee_Name: name,
  });
}
```

Somewhere in your render() method (where the text-box is rendered, perhaps not in the renderItem(). and we don't need onChange function here, because the value of the text-box will be changed automatically when we `setState`):

```
render() {
  return (
    <input type="text" value={this.state.Employee_Name} />
  );
}
```

Modify a bit in the renderItem(), to pass the Employee_Name to the handleOnclick()

```
renderItem(d, i) {


    return <tr key={i} >

  <td> {d.Employee_ID} </td>
        <td>{d.Employee_Name}</td>
        <td>{d.Address }</td> 
        <td><center><button className ="btn btn-info" onClick={this.handleOnclick.bind(this, d.Employee_ID, d.Employee_Name)}   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#UpdateEmployee">Edit</button></center></td>
  <td><center><button className ="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></center></td>

 </tr>
}
```

Please also post here more code if this doesn't work yet, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, but it seems that you can speak Japanese, too, right! Glad you've got it working, how about an up-vote, too haha. Thanks!

Comment: voted sorry it took long i was inactive last weekeng

Comment: Thanks, glad you had it working. Feel free to ping me for further reactjs issue

Comment: really i can? I have plenty more of things to learn, I might spam you questions >.< lol

Comment: That's OK, you may either ping me, or create new questions then provide me the links, thanks ^^